JavaScript Firefox print events not working
=== 1 ===
using this is not working as intended:
  window.addEventListener("beforeprint", () => calendarBeforePrint(calendarVariableName));
  window.addEventListener("afterprint", () => calendarBeforePrint(calendarVariableName));

In Chromium browsers:

when print preview opens: beforeprint is triggered
when print preview closes: afterprint is triggered

In Firefox:

when print preview opens: beforeprint is triggered AND afterprint is triggered
when print preview closes: (nothing is triggered)

=== 2 ===
Catching the change of orientation (portrait or landscape) works in Chromium browsers, but not in Firefox:
if (window.matchMedia) {
    let mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
    mediaQueryList.addListener((mql) => {
        if (mql.matches) {
            calendarBeforePrint(calendar1);
        }
    })
}

Tested on Firefox 129.0 64bit.
I am doing something wrong? Are there other functions, events or objects in Firefox? Or does Firefox just follows a different approach?
(I am trying some tricky ways as worksaround (not found yet). For some parts CSS could also be used.)


Looks like a bug in Firefox. I can confirm it and I would create an issue for this. Firefox doesn't behave as described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/afterprint_event or I don't understand the description. It seems like it was already fixed, but I can reproduce it in current Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1685011



Seems to be related to 1). I've read some comments in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1685011 and it seems like Firefox has its own approach. They clone the original document. That means that changes in the print dialog don't affect the original document. I would open another issue for this, because that behavior is probably not according to the specification.


@ jabaa thanks for clarification. Is it possible to work with the cloned document?

I have no idea. Today, I've read the first time about all of this. I don't know more than you.

Reported the bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1912881
